# using crontab to call a webmethod every week?

Tags: java, soap, cron, soapui

I am new to crontab and I wanted to know how I could call a web method every week using crontab.

I have a webmethod in java and I created a wsdl for these webmethods and now I am able to test this web method through the SOAP UI. What I actually thought was to create a .xml for this webmethod and then call it using crontab. But I am not sure whether it would work.I tried going through many sites and I am still not able to understand. Please elaborate and let me know how this functionality can be achieved.